# How to declare a multidimensional array variable with two or more single array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to use many simple array values to declare as multidimensional array values?

```
char[] alpha1 = {"A","B","C","D","E"};
char[] alpha2 = {"F","G","H","I","J"};
//Is it possible? Give me a solution for this situation: 
char[][] alpha = { alpha1[] , alpha2[] };
```

Comment: `char[][] alpha = { alpha1 , alpha2 };`

Comment: Yes, but `"a"` is not a `char` it is a `String`. You want `'a'`. Also compiler already knows that `alpha1` is `char[]` array so you don't need these `[]` inside `{..}`.

Comment: You should have just tried to compile it and read the errors...

Answer (score 3):

With `" "` you declare a String. Use `' '` for a character.

But yes it is possible, but you have to remove `[]`:

```
char[] alpha1 = {'A','B','C','D','E'};
char[] alpha2 = {'F','G','H','I','J'};
char[][] alpha = { alpha1 , alpha2 };
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to declare multidimensional array:

1. char[][] alpha = {{'A','B','C','D','E'}, {'F','G','H','I','J'}};
2. char[][] alpha = new char[4][];
   alpha[0] = new char[3];
   alpha[1] = new char[2];